# ¿Como puedo crear un log de errores?

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell, log

he estado probando diferentes formas para que me registrara en un .log si habia algun tipo de error y revisando algunas paginas no lo dejan del todo claro, simplemente queria registrar si ocurria algun fallo durante la ejecucion del script

```
do
    case $opt in 

        "detener") echo "Has elegido detener el contenedor $CONT " 
                detener_maquina; break 
        ;;

        "iniciar") echo "Has elegido iniciar el contenedor $CONT " 
                iniciar_maquina; break 
        ;;

        "ram") echo "Has elegido gestionar la RAM del contenedor $CONT "
                gestion_ram; break 
        ;;

        "cpu") echo "Has elegido gestionar la CPU del contenedor $CONT"
                gestion_cpu; break 
        ;;
        "salir") break 2
        ;;
        *) echo "Opcion no válida."
    esac
done
```

Por si es necesario dejo el codigo de una de las funciones:

```
function gestion_ram ()  {

                echo "$CONT"

                sleep 1
                        read -p "Escribe a cuanto quieres limitar la RAM
" RAM
                sleep 1
                        echo "Has seleccionado $RAM"
                sleep 1
                        echo "Se esta cambiando el limite de la ram a $RAM ..."
                sleep 2
                        $(lxc config set $CONT limits.memory $RAM)
                sleep 1
                        $(lxc config show $CONT > ram_limite.txt)
                sleep 1
                        echo "Te hemos enviado el registro a estado_ram_cpu.txt"
                sleep 1
                        $(sed '2,9d' ram_limite.txt > ram2.txt )
                        sed '4,$d' ram2.txt > estado_ram_cpu.txt
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo hay que redirigir el `stderr` al `stdout` y guardarlo en un archivo:

```
(gestion_ram 2>&1) > ./log.log; break
```

El *2* es el `stderr` y el *1* es el `stdout`, luego se guarda en el archivo `./log`

Así es con cada comando que quieras guardar:

```
(iniciar_maquina 2>&1) > ./log.log; break
```

El archivo con el comando `cat`:

```
cat ./log.log
```

Comment: Gracias me ha servido